# Is there any difference between "come to one's place" and "come out to one's place"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me if there there is any difference between *come to one's place* and *come **out** to one's place*? For example:

> Is it OK with you if we have a technician **come to your place** and fix the stove.
>
> Is it OK with you if we have a technician **come out to your place** and fix the stove.

Comment: None that I know of. I would understand _out_ to mean _out from our place_ if all the technicians were based at the firm's headquarters, or _out of town_ if the customer lived in the country.

Comment: In most if not all contexts, it's entirely a stylistic choice whether to include the optional additional preposition ***out*** between ***come*** and ***to** [some proposed destination]*. Arguably *sometimes* it might perhaps add emphasis to the proposed *travel distance.* (So in the above example, you might feasibly get charged more if they ask the ***second*** question, which implies they think it's a long way for their technician to ***drive out*** to your property! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Out* in *come out to your place* sounds a bit off or rather unnecessary to me.

*Out* usually implies an outward movement, whether literally (*come out with a remark* = suddenly say it, *come out on strike* = go on strike, *come out for a drink* = go somewhere, socialise) or figuratively (*come out against/for something* = reveal one's opposition/support, *come out* = reveal one's identity).

It's quite obvious that the technician will have to leave their office (=come out) to visit you, and I am not sure it needs to be stressed.

I would keep it simple: *come to your place* or *come over [to your place]*.